# From facebook token to jwt token

Tags: angularjs, facebook, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm using the passport module to authenticate a user and generate a jwt token.

Now I want to make facebook login possible. I'm in the phase that I get a fb token and facebook id.

What am I supposed to do with this info? Currently I make a new user that has a variable with facebook id but without a password.

Without a password I can't generate a jwt token, thus I cannot login.

How does this work?

My front end is angular and my API is written with nodejs, express & mongoose.

Passport code:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

generatejwt code:

```
UserSchema.methods.generateJWT = function() {

    // set expiration to 60 days
    var today = new Date();
    var exp = new Date(today);
    exp.setDate(today.getDate() + 60);

    return jwt.sign({
        _id: this._id,
        username: this.username,
        exp: parseInt(exp.getTime() / 1000),
    }, 'SECRET');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 routes :

1) This will be called to login to facebook.

2)Callback route if the user authentication is successful.(This callback route needs to be registered in the facebook developer portal.

```
//Facebook Login
app.route('/auth/facebook')
.get(passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));
// Callback
app.route('/auth/facebook/callback')
.get(passport.authenticate('facebook'),users.generateJWT);
```

Define a facebook strategy that will store the user details (id, token, email) in your database

```
var facebookStrategy = new FacebookStrategy({  
clientID: cfg.facebook.clientID,
clientSecret: cfg.facebook.clientSecret,
callbackURL: cfg.facebook.callbackURL,
profileFields: ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
},
function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  console.log("Token: "+ token);
  console.log("RefreshToken: "+ refreshToken);
  console.log("profile: "+ profile);
  process.nextTick(function() {
   User.findOne({ 'facebook.id': profile.id }, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
      return done(err);
    if (user) {
        console.log("User Found");
      return done(null, user);
    } else {
        console.log("Creating user");
      var newUser = new User();
      console.log("Token: "+ token);
      newUser.facebook.id = profile.id;
      newUser.facebook.token = token;
      newUser.facebook.name = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName;
      newUser.facebook.email = (profile.emails[0].value || '').toLowerCase();

      newUser.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
          throw err;
        return done(null, newUser);
      });
    }
  });
});
});
```

In the controller, write the below code for callback route:

```
/**
* Generate JWT Token 
*/
 exports.generateJWT = function(req, res) {
 var token;
             token = req.user.generateJwt();
             res.status(200);
             res.json({
                "token" : token
              });
  };
```